# How to check if file already exists, if not, download on Python?

Tags: python, json, image, parsing

i'm downloading images (my favorites) from Flickr with Python, but when i do this process, i want to check if the image has already been downloaded.
I tried writing the IDs of the downloades files on a TXT file and check it, but doesn't work.

*e.g
I download the 5 last images I tagged as favorite, and I already downloaded them, but I tag another one, so the N1 hasn't been downloaded, but the other 4 have, so I want to donwload only the "missing" one, not the 4 others.*

Part where i get the images, but the if doesn't work:

```
for item in pics:
if item['id'] in open("id.txt").read():
    print "Exists"
else:
    file.write(item['id'] + "\n")
    image = str("http://www.flickr.com/" + item['owner'] + "/" + item['id'] + "/sizes/l/")
    website = urllib2.urlopen(image)
    html = website.read()
    links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', html)
    filter = links[0][0]
    end = filter.replace("_m.jpg", "_b.jpg")
    urllib.urlretrieve(end, "FlickFavorite(" + str(n) + ").jpg")
    print ult
    n += 1
```

**Thanks a lot for your help!**

Comment: You can use `os.path.exists(filename)` to check for files on your computer.

Comment: @figs But if i want to check multiple files? That wont work quickly

Comment: You'd have to check one by one before you download each file. Can't imagine that would be slow compared to the time taken to download each file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

os.path.isfile(file_to_check)
```

will accomplish the task.

```
os.path.exists(file_to_check)
```

would also work, but would  return true for a directory as well. That may not be what you want always.

If you want to check for multiple files in a known directory, one way to do it is this: you could get a list of files (and directories) using

```
file_list = os.listdir(directory_to_check)
```

then iterate through the list of files, possibly checking for matches to filenames you are interested in in the list, then check if each file exists.

Comment: But i want to check multiple files (5 files)

Comment: for item in pics:
      if not os.path.isfile(filename): download(file_url)
?